# Is my logic correct? It is giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I want to find the maximum sum from the root to a leaf in a binary tree.
Initially I am doing: `Answer= sum_to_leaf(root,0);`
I know the other way to explore all the path and update a global maximum for the sum. I just want to do it this way.

```
int sum_to_leaf(struct node* root, int sum)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return sum;

    else if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        sum = sum + root->data;
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        sum = sum + root->data;
        if(sum_to_leaf(root->left, sum) > sum_to_leaf(root->right, sum))
        {
            sum = sum + sum_to_leaf(root->left, sum);
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + sum_to_leaf(root->right, sum);
        }
        return sum; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but anyway you should not call twice a recursing function with the same intent. Store `sum_to_leaf(root->left,sum)` and `sum_to_leaf(root->right,sum)` into integers before comparing them and assigning them.

Comment: I think people here don't take very well questions where you ask for the correctness of your logic. You can just run your program, and ask for help if it doesn't work, providing that you document what's not working properly.

Comment: I don't see anything right off in that code taht woudl cause a segmentation fault. However, it appears to be a small segment of your code, so the segfault could be happening elsewhere. You need to do a little debugging to narrow down where the culprit is. And I agree with @Eregrith that calling, for example, `sum_to_leaf(root->left,sum)` twice is wasteful. You should call it once and save the value for use in the sum.

Comment: Is this C or C++? You have both tags, but they are different languages. Similar ones in some respects, true, but so are Java and C#.

Comment: @anjruu the use of the struct keyword strongly suggests C, but might also be C++ written by someone who's only learnt C

Comment: @benjymous Yeah, it looks like plain ol' C to me, but I wanted to make the point more than actually get clarification. Regardless, someone who's been around here longer than I have been might want to remove one of the tags.

Comment: I am using C++. I tagged it in C as well because that part would be the same in both I guess.
Commenting off this section is removing the seg fault problem. So I guess this section only has the problem.

Comment: @Shivendra Just because this is the point where the segfault is happening doesn't mean the problem is here. The problem is _almost certainly_ that a node in your tree has uninitialized `data`, `right` or `left`. Given this, the problem is probably in the code where you construct the tree, and you're only seeing the segfault here because this is where you use the tree.

Also, if this is C++, you don't need the `struct` keyword.

Comment: I figured out the problem with seg fault. Learnt some useful things from the replies here.
Thanks.

Comment: @Shivendra What was the problem?

Comment: @anjruu I posted this due to the seg fault error. I was not returning the pointer to the heap of memory I assigned by `malloc` properly leading to the seg fault. But when it got corrected I was getting wrong output. My logic was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm are you sure the segfault is from that code? Have you debugged it?
I'd rather try this:

```
int sum_to_leaf(struct node* root,int sum) {

    if(root==NULL) {
        return sum;    
    } else {
        sum=sum+root->data;
        int left_sum = sum_to_leaf(root->left, sum);
        int right_sum = sum_to_leaf(root->right, sum);

        return std::max(left_sum, right_sum); // need to #include <algorithm>
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to include sum in your return. `return sum + std::max(...)`

Comment: Eregrith there's no need for that, as both left_sum and right_sum will already have that value included.

Comment: Oh yes... sorry. Not enough coffee ^^"

Comment: @Eregrith think you were right. he adds in sum in the original code. Not sure it's right but it's what it does.

Comment: Well that's wrong in the original code then. Think of it. If you have the root and call `sum_to_leaf(root->left, sum)`, there isn't any "root->left", therefore sum_to_leaf returns just `sum` (first `if` case). Why would I add `sum` again?

Answer (score 0):

You must be incorrectly building your tree.  Somewhere you're accessing an uninitialised `node` though `root->` and getting a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

I guess better way to implement ur algorithm is:

```
int getSum(struct node* nd)
{
    if(nd==NULL)
        return 0;
    int sum_r = getSum(nd->right);
    int sum_l = getSum(nd->left);
    return nd->data + std::max(sum_r, sum_l);
}
```